# Consul back up strategy (service discovery, consensus)

Tags: backup, snapshot, consul, service-discovery, leader

I am interested in creating backups (snapshots) for data being stored in consul. I am using it as my backend storage for my service. I found few tools like consulate, consul-backup which take snapshots for the data which consul stores on the disk. Imagine, I have a 5 node set up where consul is running on all the 5 hosts and we have a quorum of 3. One of them is going to be the leader. With different back up strategies implemented, which backup the data on every single host, does it make more sense to back up only the leader ? The leader would be expected to maintain the most latest state of data. Then why do we need to back up every single host? And if we decide to back up just the leader, then if the leadership changes while the data was being backed up, would that result into any issues ?